# Prove that $\left(a-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(b-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(c-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\geq\frac{3}{4}$

Tags: inequality

Let $a, b, c$  are non-negative real numbers satisfy $a+b+c=3$. Prove that $$\left(a-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(b-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(c-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\geq\frac{3}{4}$$

Comment: i haven't idea for this post, help me !

Comment: Have you copied the question wrong? Are there more conditions on $a,b,c$?

Comment: oh, i'm sorry because my foolishness

Comment: So is the question you typed here the correct one?

Comment: and what is the correct Statement?

Comment: sorry i don't know fix where

Answer (score 2):

It's wrong! Try please $a=b=c=1$.

Comment: you can fix it ?

Comment: @Word Shallow  What do you mean?

Comment: you can fix my question ?

Comment: @Word Shallow Tell my, what I need to write and I'll fix.

Comment: @Word Shallow I found the following similar question. Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be real numbers such that $a+b+c=3$. Prove that: $\left(a-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(b-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(c-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\geq\frac{3}{4}$

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that $RMS\geq A.M$

$\sqrt{\dfrac{\left(a-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(b-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(c-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2}{3}}\geq \dfrac{\left(a-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)+\left(b-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)+\left(c-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)}{3}$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\left(a-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(b-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(c-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 &\ge \frac{\left(\left|a-\frac{1}{2} \right| +\left|b-\frac{1}{2} \right|+\left|c-\frac{1}{2} \right|\right)^2}{3}\\
&\ge \frac{\left(\left|a-\frac{1}{2} + b-\frac{1}{2}+c-\frac{1}{2} \right|\right)^2}{3}\\
&= \frac{3}{4}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Cauchy Schwarz:

$$u+v+w = (1,1,1) \cdot  (u,v,w)   \le \sqrt{3} \sqrt{ u^2+v^2 + w^2},$$

with equality if and only if $u=v=w\ge 0$.

Set $u=a-\frac12,v=b-\frac 12,w=c-\frac 12$ and square both sides to obtain

$$\frac 94 \le 3 \left (  (a-\frac 12)^2 + (b-\frac 12)^2 + (c-\frac 12)^2  \right)$$

Divid both sides by $3$ to obtain the result, with equality if and only if $a=b=c=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, for any real numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$, we have

$$\begin{align}
0&\le(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\\
&=2(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)\\
&=3(a^2+b^2+c^2)-(a+b+c)^2
\end{align}$$

Now if $a+b+c=3$, then $0\le3(a^2+b^2+c^2)-3(a+b+c)$, which, on dropping the $3$ and adding three $1\over4$'s on both sides, leads to

$$\begin{align}
{3\over4}&\le\left(a^2-a+{1\over4}\right)+\left(b^2-b+{1\over4}\right)+\left(c^2-c+{1\over4}\right)\\
&=\left(a-{1\over2}\right)^2+\left(b-{1\over2}\right)^2+\left(c-{1\over2}\right)^2
\end{align}$$

The assumption that $a$, $b$ and $c$ are non-negative is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** this question  includes strong geometric interpretation: $a+b+c=3$ represents a plane in 3D space, and inequality is a presentation of a sphere. Calculate the distance from the plane to the centre of sphere.